# Rselenium in parallel: error when try to open page in a node

Tags: r, rselenium, doparallel

On following site: [Run RSelenium in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950958/run-rselenium-in-parallel), I have found out how to open multiply browsers (sessions) in parallel using parallel package:

```
 library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# number of cores
(cl <- (detectCores() - 1) %>%  makeCluster) %>% registerDoParallel

# open a remoteDriver for each node on the cluster
# docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(RSelenium)
  remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L,
                        browserName = "chrome")
  remDr$open()

})
```

But if I add only one additional line of code that open specific page:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(RSelenium)
  remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L,
                        browserName = "chrome")
  remDr$open()
  Sys.sleep(3L)
  remDr$navigate("http://plovila.pomorstvo.hr/")
})
```

it returns an error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  6 nodes produced errors; first error:      Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Why it returns an error with this additional line of code?

There is one more strange thing. It sometimes works at firs, but after if I try more times it returns an error all the time.

Comment: I believe it is because you are trying to open several remotedriver on the same port. You need to open them using different ports.

Comment: Could you show how can I do that? I suppose that, first, I have to  run different docker containers?