# Run yaml file for parallel selenium test from R or python

Tags: python, r, docker, selenium-grid, rselenium

I have a simple yaml file:

```
seleniumhub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

firefoxnode:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    ports:
      - 4577
    links:
      - seleniumhub:hub

chromenode:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    ports:
      - 4578
    links:
      - seleniumhub:hub
```

that I have executed in docker:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I have one hub and two nodes running.

Now I would like to run two very simple selenium commands in parallel (written in RSelenium):

```
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

I would like to know how can I run above selenium commands in Python or R, in parallel. I tried several ways but none works. For example in R:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4444L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

doesn't do anything. I have also tried to run two remoteDrivers, but that doesn't help ether:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4577L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

Comment: Something similar, example for node: https://github.com/xbx/webdriverio-docker-example

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it in R or Python, because I am not familiar with JavaScript, Java or C# (I have found the solution in those 3 languages).

Comment: Define parallel here, you want to run same commands on two browsers ? Can you run two scripts or you want to run them with same script and use threads?

Comment: I would like to run as much browsers as possible (only contraint is RAM), from one R or Python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is duplicate of

[Run RSelenium in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950958/run-rselenium-in-parallel)

You can use code in above answer to do parallel execution

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

URLsPar <- c("http://www.bbc.com/", "http://www.cnn.com", "http://www.google.com",
             "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.twitter.com")
appHTML <- c()

(cl <- (detectCores() - 1) %>%  makeCluster) %>% registerDoParallel
# open a remoteDriver for each node on the cluster
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(RSelenium)
  remDr <- remoteDriver$new(remoteServerAddr = ip, port = port)
  remDr$open()
})
myTitles <- c()
ws <- foreach(x = 1:length(URLsPar), .packages = c("rvest", "magrittr", "RSelenium"))  %dopar%  {
  remDr$navigate(URLsPar[x])
  remDr$getTitle()[[1]]
}

# close browser on each node
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  remDr$close()
})

stopImplicitCluster()
```