# Run Selenium parallel test on Azure batch

Tags: r, selenium, foreach, rselenium, azure-batch

I am using latest version of R on windows 7.

I would like to run many test in parallel using `RSelenium` so, my question is:

- What is the recommended way to run many `RSelenium` tests?

Let's say I would like to run 1000 tests and each step takes 1 hour. Running tests one by one takes lot's of time (24 test per day, so in total cca 42 days). I know how to use doParallel and foreach package to run tests in parallel on my machine: [Run RSelenium in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950958/run-rselenium-in-parallel),
but sometimes, this is not enough. I would like like to run around 100 tests in parallel. I tried to use Azure Batch for that, but get lot's of errors on some nodes when starting the selenium server.

More concretely, I have written dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-base:latest 

RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
   libxml2-dev \
   libcurl4-openssl-dev \
   libssl-dev \
   gnupg2 \
   libfftw3-dev \
   libtiff-dev \
   libx11-dev \
   libcairo2-dev \
   libxt-dev \
   firefox

#RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next

## Install Java 
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" \ 
        | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list \ 
    && echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" \ 
        | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list \ 
    && apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886 \ 
    && echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" \ 
        | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections \ 
    && apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer \ 
    && update-alternatives --display java \ 
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \ 
    && apt-get clean \ 
    && R CMD javareconf 

## make sure Java can be found in rApache and other daemons not looking in R ldpaths 
RUN echo "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/rJava.conf 
RUN /sbin/ldconfig

# Install the R Packages from CRAN
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("Cairo", "Rcpp", "RSelenium", "httr", "rvest", "imager", "RCurl"))'
```

I have used `doAzureParallel` package to execute many scripts in parallel:

```
# prepare Azure batch
setwd("E:/data/R/web_scraping/zk_ba/azure")
library(doAzureParallel) 
setVerbose(TRUE)
setAutoDeleteJob(FALSE)
generateCredentialsConfig("credentials.json") 
setCredentials("credentials.json")
generateClusterConfig("cluster.json")
cluster <- makeCluster("cluster.json") 
registerDoAzureParallel(cluster) 
getDoParWorkers()
opt <- list(wait = FALSE) 

jobId <- foreach(
  i = 1:n_cluster, 
  # .packages = c("RSelenium", "imager", "httr", "RCurl", "rvest"),
  # .combine = 'rbind',
  .errorhandling = "pass",
  .options.azure = opt, 
  .export = c("metadata", "first_step", "parcele_df", "vlasnici_df", "status_teret_df", "n_cluster")
) %dopar% { 

  library(RSelenium)
  library(imager)
  library(httr)
  library(RCurl)
  library(rvest)

  #-----------------------------------#
  #    START SELENIUM AND PREPARE     #
  #-----------------------------------#

  if (first_step == TRUE) {
    tryCatch({
      rD <<- RSelenium::rsDriver(
        browser = "firefox",
        extraCapabilities = list(
          "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
            args = list('--headless')
          )
        )
      )
    }, error = function(e) NA)
    driver <<- rD$client
    driver$open()
    driver$navigate("http://www.e-grunt.ba/")
    Sys.sleep(3L)
..
}
```

but this return error on many nodes:

```
<simpleError in checkError(res): Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused>
```

What would be general advice in situations where we need to use RSelenium in lot's of parallel tests?

Comment: But I think I have to start driver on VM,, not on every node, and I am using 4 VM's and 4 nodes. I don't know why same port would be a problem if VM's are independent from on to another. I have also tried to run Selenium session in parallel o lokal port and I called rsDriver function only once. All other nodes successfully listened this driver on one port.

Comment: are you trying to run your case on Azure DevOps pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

`RSelenium` connects to the Selenium server it sets up on port `4567` by default. As soon as one of the parallel nodes connects to the server via this port, no other node can connect through this port.

A solution is to add the following argument to the `rsDriver` in the `foreach` loop:

```
rD <<- RSelenium::rsDriver(
        port = 4567L + as.integer(i),
        browser = "firefox",
        extraCapabilities = list(
          "moz:firefoxOptions" = list(
            args = list('--headless')
          )
        )
```

You may have to check for clashes of the ports with other applications.